Как перенести значения переменных в коде в другой код в питон?
Например, есть программа main.py и в папке, в которой находится этот код есть еще одна папка под названием "next", в которой находится main2.py.
Моя задача перенести переменные a и b из main.py в main2.py. 
Как это сделать?
main.py
import os
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
os.startfile(os.getcwd() + r'\next\main2.py')

main2.py
print(a + b)


оберните код в который нужно передать аргументы в функцию, которая принимает на вход аргументы, импортируйте функцию в код от куда нужно передать аргументы, вызовите функцию передав в неё аргументы

Да. Я знаю что так можно сделать, но файл main2.py находится в другой папке.

sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'next')) что-то вроде этого? Это задаст путь к вашему каталогу в переменную окружения используемую питоном.

Я не очень понимаю как это применить

Можно передать аргументы в вызываемый скрипт. Хотя потом придётся результат ещё обратно принимать.

Как вариант:
q1581143_main.py:
from next.q1581143_main2 import sum_a_b

def main_function(): 
    flag = True
    while flag:
        try:
            a = int(input("\nВведите первое число: "))
            b = int(input("Введите второе число: "))
            
            sum_of_numbers = sum_a_b(a, b)
            print(f'main.py ; sum_of_numbers = {sum_of_numbers}')
            flag = False
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'\nmain.py ; Введите правильно данные; \n\t{e}\n')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main_function()


q1581143_main2.py:
def sum_a_b(a, b): 
    sum_of_numbers = a + b
    print(f'main2.py; sum_a_b(a, b): {sum_of_numbers}')
    return sum_of_numbers






@KREEPAR123 что не так?
